# Git clone --reference and concurrent updates

Tags: git, concurrency

I'm currently investigating whether it would be safe to use `git clone --reference` as an optimization when there are many users and the referenced repo is updated automatically (and frequently).

The plan is that there would be many users, on one server, all using a number of large repositories where the main repository is remote (and therefore slow).

In order to optimize both initial clone speed and server disk space, the users will use a clone script that does `git clone --reference /home/robot/repo.git <repo>` so that most of the data is shared.

The "robot" user will do frequent `git fetch` operations on a cron job.

Now, I know that concurrent access to Git repositories is safe when they're both owned by the same user and/or the directories are writeable, but in this case the reference repo would be read-only, as a first preference, so the users will not be able to write lock files there.

My question is, what happens if the "robot" repo does a fetch/gc/repack while another user is accessing the repository? Does clone/fetch/pull fall-back to fetching from the remote repo, slowly? Do other commands like log/checkout/rebase fail? Can corruption occur in the user repos?

Notes:

- I'm sure the user process can check if the repo is locked *before* it starts to read; I'm asking about write operations that happen *during* the read.
- I'm aware that the documentation says that garbage collect can break referenced clones, but in this case there will only be fast-forward updates, so nothing will get removed, only repacked.
- I've looked at the documentation, and the word "concurrent" does not appear, so I'm struggling to find an official statement on the subject.
- Most other questions on this site are about concurrent pulls, pushes, and fetches, in which case it is safe because those operations are atomic (the refs have either changed, or they have not); the case of shared or referenced clones seems less obviously safe, as it needs continuous access to the packed object files.
- This is on a Linux system using a local filesystem, so there are no network problems, and no variations in OS support, different Git versions, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're safe for a bunch of fairly complicated reasons.

Basically, `--reference` cloning (without `--dissociate`):

- writes the path to the reference into `.git/objects/info/alternates` (see [the `gitrepository-layout` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrepository-layout.html))
- For each commit ID for which it's about to say "want", looks in the alternates to see if it can find that object.

Suppose that some sort of update is happening to the alternate while this is occurring.  Your clone has some hash value and is in the process of answering the question: "is this object in the alternate?"

Suppose that the answer it finds is "no".  It will then retrieve the object from the original instead, and will retain that object forever (or until it's no longer needed after all, whichever comes first), so in this case you are fine.

Suppose instead that it finds the answer is "yes, the object is in the alternate."  There are two possibilities:

- the object is stored as a loose object, or
- the object is in a pack.

If the object is loose *now*, but is in the process of being packed, the object will soon appear in a pack, after which the loose object will be unlinked.  The reference git repository will not unlink the loose object until the pack is fully written to stable storage.  Hence, even if your clone finishes in the middle of this sequence and you run another git command that needs the object, it will either find the loose object, or find the pack.

- If your finds the loose object, it does so by opening the file.  This means that when the reference repository's git command unlinks the file, your git already has it open and can use it.
- If your git finds the object in a pack, it does so by opening the pack-file.  This means that if the pack-file is repacked and removed (unlinked), your git already has it open and can use it.  Since pack-files are self-contained,<sup>1</sup> the open file suffices.

The only time any of this goes wrong is if you allow the reference repository to *delete* objects (via `gc` or similar), which is what the documentation warns about.  If you have the object open (in loose or packed form) you're OK but once it's gone, a *later* attempt to find it, won't.

All of this is contingent on the OS keeping the file around even when it's being removed.  Some file systems (*cough*NFS*cough*) don't necessarily behave correctly, and of course any kind of remote, over-the-net file systems (Dropbox for instance) can cause issues as well.  As long as you stick with local file systems (and your hardware does not fail) you should be fine.

---

<sup>1</sup>Except for "thin packs" which are not visible here anyway.

Comment: Thank you. The key point I understand is that the object may be there twice, but never not there, and pack files are created atomically. This is reassuring. :-)

Comment: They're not truly atomic, but they *simulate* atomicity (I've only recently convinced $work to use reference clones so we don't have lots of experience yet, but so far so good :-) ).

Comment: Creating a file on the side, and then moving it into position is as atomic as it gets in filesystems. I'll take that.

Comment: Oh, I see, it may not do that, but the client will see the loose object first so doesn't get to the pack file. Hmm, less confident with that.